# Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I can't star mysql and all the solutions people tell me doesn't work.

```
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
```

I already tried to

```
mv ibdata1 ibdata1.bak
mv ib_logfile ib_logfile.bak
cp -a ibdata1.bak ibdata1
cp -a ib_logfile.bak ib_logfile
```

And it didn't work. I still have the same error. I removed the install with purge and tried to install it again. Same thing.

I'm running out of options here. Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 3):

This is actually simply just kill the mysql instances and mysql will be able to start again.

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop

service mysql stop

killall -KILL mysql mysqld_safe mysqld
```